# Efficient dynamic-generated Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I am building a Java SingStar-like application, and I need some help since I am not very experienced with Java Swing despite all the basic knowledge about layouts and so on.

My intentions are the following:

1. Open a Midi file.
2. Read the notes.
3. Generate the GUI showing this data.
4. Displace the GUI constantly while playing.

What I thought about (and did) is creating a BufferedImage representing the Midi data. So, for example, I have a MidiLength x ScreenHeight BufferedImage (typically 1024 x >10.000) which I fill dynamically reading the midi data. Then I show the first ScreenWidth x ScreenHeight  part of the BufferedImage, and when user starts playing I update the BufferedImage subimage x starting coordinate every 5ms. This way I successfully achieve what I am looking for.

I am posting an image of the GUI so you can get a better idea of what I am talking about.

http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/3324/javagui.png

The problem is that this internal BufferedImage can be pretty huge, depending on the Midi length, so it is taking lots of RAM, but I can't think of other way for doing this.

Any idea would be pretty much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you "stream" the buffered image so it's only using ram for what's on the screen?

Comment: The problem there would be that I would need to generate the image "on the fly", and its very dynamic (changing every few milliseconds).  I could generate image windows of fixed sizes (for example of 1024x4000) and generate the next ones coming "on the fly". But I would like to think about other solution, if it exists, since I don't want to stress the CPU with the GUI since I would be using a good % performing different calculations. Anyway thank you so much for your answer, I would implement this if there's no other solution.

Comment: Cant you make your own JPanel and draw it dynamically? Thats the easiest way... From your screenshot, I'd say that would be really easy, and would be fast and memory efficient...

Comment: What happens if the user resizes the window?

Comment: BufferedImage is scaled to fit user window from original. If original its 1024x768 and screen size is 1280x1024, 1024x768 gets scaled to 1280x1024.

Comment: To my mind, 5 milliseconds is near enough to 0 that makes no difference. Generally speaking most users won't see much over around 25fps (and screens won't be able refresh much faster), which puts your updates at around 40 millisecond. You'd be better off placing your notes information and so me kind of list and rendering only what's viewable on each cycle

Comment: I'd like to show you the real program so you could see how 10ms makes a big difference to 5ms. The problem is that the image is moving from right to left on the screen and it contains text that needs to be read. The movement has to be very smooth, otherwise it is not comfortable to read. Anyway, I will be considering generating the image on the fly, but maybe it's a worse solution than using 300Mb of RAM. I'll post here whatever result I get! Thanks very much for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should just write a custom Swing component and do all the drawing in 
`paintComponent(Graphics)` method, instead of generating the image.

Check [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62099/UI-Component-Development-in-Java-Swing-Part-1-Desi) to speed up the process.

Comment: Thanks Hakan, I am going to try to implement this "computing the GUI on the fly" solution. But I am expecting some undesired CPU usage, since I would have to read the "midi" position each, let's say again, 5ms, and then realize what needs to be shown on the screen and paint it. Anyway, I will post here whatever result I get!

Comment: Let's wait and see the results then :)